# Como cambiar texto de un Textbox al seleccionar el dato de otro?

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, combobox

Tengo estos Combobox en un form los cuales al Iniciarse la aplicación se llenan con los datos que estan en una BD, como puedo hacer para que si en el de ID selecciono el "2", el combo de Nombre mueste el nombre que corresponde a ese ID y viseversa?? [image: Combos a Cambiar]

Con esto se llenan los combos

//--------------Combo ID de Contratista------------------------------

```
        query = "select Cont_ID from Sec_Obra_Contrato";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Cbox_ID_Contratista.Items.Add(dr["Cont_ID"].ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
```

//--------------Combo Nombre de Contratista------------------------------

```
query = "select Cont_Nombre_Contratista from Sec_Obra_Contrato"; cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con); con.Open(); dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); while (dr.Read()) { Cbox_NameContratista.Items.Add(dr["Cont_Nombre_Contratista"].ToString()); } con.Close();
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Todo depende si es wpf, winforms o lo que sea que estes usando, y como cargas ese combo.. usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda esa informacion

Comment: Windows Forms produce eventos de acuerdo a las diferentes interacciones que ocurran. Puedes consultar los de [`ComboBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-uw/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox#events) y deducir que los que te interesan son `SelectedValueChanged` o `SelectedIndexChanged`. Si estás en WPF deberías poder hacer un procedimiento similar.

Comment: Precisamente habia utilizado el  Value Changed, pero me ocasiono conflicto al seleccionar un nombre, tendra algun ejemplo en el que me pueda basar??

Comment: Copié mal el enlace. [Este es](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox#events). No puedo darte ejemplos de SQL en específico. Si explicas cuál es el problema que obtienes en la pregunta te podrían ayudar.

Answer (score -1):

Al no ver el código es un poco difícil descifrar como está realizado, pero podrías poner un if simplemente validando que al seleccionar o ingresar el id del contratista seleccione al contratista con el mismo id

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Si habia pensado con un if, pero no entiendo por que a la hora de selecionar un nombre marca un error (que no grabe) y en consecuente no cambia el id